# Drawing circuits for raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I was looking for a tool that can help me draw the circuit that I have created more like the one in the following link.

[An example I found online](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/MCP3008_TMP36-1024x704.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This image was most likely made using Fritzing. (http://fritzing.org/home/) It's useful to do a reverse image search (https://images.google.com), upload the image you've got, and search for visually similar images. In this case, I found a very similar image that had a watermark that said "Created using fritzing.org"

Comment: Thanks, That was it :). Could you post that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image was most likely made using Fritzing. (http://fritzing.org/home) It's useful to do a reverse image search (https://images.google.com), upload the image you've got, and search for visually similar images. In this case, I found a very similar image that had a watermark that said "Created using fritzing.org".